# Proving inequality using Taylor polynomial of arctan

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, functional-inequalities

I have to prove that $ x - \frac{x^3}{3} < \arctan(x) < x - \frac{x^3}{6} $ is true if $ 0 < x \leq 1 $

I tried to convert the second inequality into the one I'm trying to prove. Since $ \arctan(x) $ is a monotonically increasing function, applying it to each part of the second inequality should not change the relationships:
$$ 0 < x \leq 1 \Rightarrow \arctan(0) < \arctan(x) \leq \arctan(1) $$

Then I calculated the 3rd degree Taylor polynomial of $ \arctan(x) $ centered at $ x = 0 $ and at $ x = 1 $ to approximate the left and right sides of the inequality:

$$ \arctan(0) \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3} $$

$$ \arctan(1) \approx \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2} (x-1) + \frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2 + \frac{1}{3} (x-1)^3$$

So it's evident that $ x - \frac{x^3}{3} < \arctan(x) $ is correct. But I'm stuck trying to prove that $ \arctan(x) < x - \frac{x^3}{6} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$f(x)=\arctan x- x+\frac16 x^3 \implies f'(x)=\frac{x^2(x^2-1)}{2(x^2+1)}\le 0$$

with $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I've been re-reading this over and over trying to understand what to do hahaha. Let's see if I got it:
You took $ \arctan(x) < x - \frac{x^3}{6} $ from the first inequality, and re-wrote it as $ \arctan(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6} < 0 $. Then you defined the expr of the left side as f(x), calculated f'(x), determined f'(x) < 0 in the interval $ 0 < x \leq 1 $, and since f(0) = 0, it means that f(x) < 0 is true too, therefore proving the original inequality. Is that right?

Comment: Yes this is a standard way to prove such kind of inequalities.